# My function returned value is not global and won't end the "while" loop

Tags: python

```
done = False
player_health = 2
def lost_game(done):
    if player_health <= 0:
        done = True
        print ('You died')
        return done
while not done:
    print 'okay'
    player_health -= 1
```

I can't figure out why `done` is never set to `True`, thus ending the while loop.

Comment: Where do you call `lost_game()`? It returns the value, you should assign that to a variable in the loop.

Comment: Why does `lost_game()` take `done` as a parameter? It never uses it.

Comment: Yeah, my bad! Prune corrected me down below. I didn't realize that I didn't need "done" as a parameter. For not calling the function, I just forgot to copy+paste it. Thank you for the help! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not set to True because it's a local variable.
If you want to affect the global variable with a function assignment, you have to declare it such:

```
def lost_game():
    global done
    if player_health <= 0:
        done = True
```

Also, note that you've never called the `lost_game` function.  I'm not sure what control flow you expect.  It *looks* like you might intend a simple loop:

```
done = False
player_health = 2
while not done:
    if player_health <= 0:
        done = True
        print ('You died')

print 'okay'
player_health -= 1
```

... or perhaps it's simply your failure to call the function and capture the return value:

```
done = False
player_health = 2

def lost_game():
    done = False
    if player_health <= 0:
        done = True
        print ('You died')
        return done

while not lost_game():
    print 'okay'
    player_health -= 1
```

Comment: shit sorry! This is my first year coding so I'm a little scrubby. The first one did the trick for me. I just forgot to copy and paste the full code (that's why i didn't call the function). MB! Thank you so much for the help :D

Comment: Great.  I see you've already discussed up-votes elsewhere (I've clicked a few).

Answer (score 2):

Just update your while loop:

```
while not done: 
    print 'okay' 
    player_health -= 1
    done = lost_game(done)
```

Btw there is no need to pass done in your lost_game function call.

Answer (score 1):

You're never calling `lost_game()`. `lost_game()` returns the value as a result, so you should use that rather than the variable:

```
player_health = 2

def lost_game():
    if player_health <= 0:
        print ('You died')
        return True
    else:
        return False

while not lost_game():
    print 'okay'
    player_health -= 1
```

`lost_game()` doesn't need a parameter.

Comment: Thank you :D! I don't have the rep to upvote, but just know I did! You and Prune helped me a lot. Thanks man!

Comment: Accept the most useful answer, you don't need to upvote.